# AWS wrangler writing wrong values in parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, aws-data-wrangler

NaN value in not getting written in parquet files as expected. Not sure if this is an error with awswrangler to_parquet function.

## Example:

creating the DataFrames

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']})

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).reset_index(drop=True)

df

[image]

Parquet file:

wr.s3.to_parquet(df=df, path='file_path,
dataset=True, index=False, compression='gzip', boto3_session=session)

[image]